# Yii failed to connect to postgresql database in slackware 13.37

Tags: postgresql, yii, slackware

I trying an application made in Yii 1.1.14 in slackware 13.37

When trying to connect it shows a pagae with this message:

**Error 500 

CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.**

The application.log in protected/runtime shows this

```
2017/09/07 10:32:16 [error] [exception.CDbException] could not find driver
2017/09/07 10:32:16 [error] [exception.CDbException] exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.' in /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:388
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(330): CDbConnection->open()
#1 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(308): CDbConnection->setActive(true)
#2 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/base/CModule.php(387): CDbConnection->init()
#3 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(450): CModule->getComponent('db')
#4 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(634): CApplication->getDb()
#5 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(667): CActiveRecord->getDbConnection()
#6 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(1455): CActiveRecord->getCommandBuilder()
#7 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/protected/components/UserIdentity.php(8): CActiveRecord->find('LOWER(username)...', Array)
#8 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/protected/models/LoginForm.php(52): UserIdentity->authenticate()
#9 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/validators/CInlineValidator.php(42): LoginForm->authenticate('password', Array)
#10 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/validators/CValidator.php(213): CInlineValidator->validateAttribute(Object(LoginForm), 'password')
#11 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/base/CModel.php(159): CValidator->validate(Object(LoginForm), NULL)
#12 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/protected/controllers/SiteController.php(97): CModel->validate()
#13 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): SiteController->actionLogin()
#14 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#15 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#16 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#17 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('login')
#18 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('site/login')
#19 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#20 /var/www/htdocs/myapp/index.php(14): CApplication->run()
#21 {main}

REQUEST_URI=/myapp/index.php?r=site/login
HTTP_REFERER=http://192.168.0.131/myapp/index.php?r=site/login
```

The source code of the application and its connection to the database works fine in debian and ubuntu.

Others applications made in php can can connect with the same database in the slackware server.

any help?

Comment: Do you have the php postgres extension installed?

Comment: When I run the command: `php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());" |grep pgsql`
the output is:
`[44] => pgsql`
it seems that an extension called **pdo_pgsql** is missing, but how do install it?

Comment: Please install php-pgsql library

Comment: This is slackware, php-pgsql is installed but it doesn't include pdo_pgsql, if I import it from another distro, it has to be compiled with the same API as the rest in the current distro, otherwise I have this result when I run `php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());" |grep pgsql`                       
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
    [44] => pgsql`